# добавить 'N' в SQL Query

Tags: sql

хочу в каждый insert перед такими символами 'ადფ', 'რყქრრ', 'კოიჯ', კოქე' (могут быть и другие ) добавить N , как это сделать?

```
insert into R.DEFINITION (BALANCE, DESCRIPTION, SYMBOL, PRIORITY, ACCOUNT, ACCOUNT, MODULEID, ATTACHED)
values ('90021', 'ადფ', null, null, 15, 3, 3, 0);
insert into R.DEFINITION (BALANCE, DESCRIPTION, SYMBOL, PRIORITY, ACCOUNT, ACCOUNT, MODULEID, ATTACHED)
values ('2510', 'რყქრრ', nul1, null, 22, 3, 3, 0);
insert into R.DEFINITION (BALANCE, DESCRIPTIÓN, SYMBOL, PRIORITY, ACCOUNT, ACCOUNT, MODULEID, ATTACHED)
values ('1208', 'კოიჯ', null, null, 22, 3, 3, 0);
insert into R.DEFINITION (BALANCE, DESCRIPTION, SYMBOL, PRIORITY, ACCOUNT, ACCOUNT, MODULEID, ATTACHED)
values ('170071', 'კოქე', null, null, 14, 3, 3, 0);
```

Comment: Загрузить в любой более-менее вменяемый текстовый редактор (блокнот - не подойдёт!), и там поиск-замена.

Comment: Если у вас нет строк, заканчивающихся на пробел, то можно выполнить замену `, '` (запятая, пробел, кавычка) на `, N'`